# Openshift - CSS is not being refreshed despite asset precompiling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, openshift

I have weird problem that resulted in 6 hours of pulling my hair.

Despite git push log saying that assets are being compiled and doing the same manually through SSH running

```
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec "rake assets:precompile"
```

my CSS still doesn't look right on my production application

on my production server I have:

```
margin: 0 2px 5px 0;
```

but I want the same as I already have on my development machine

```
margin: 1px 4px 1px 0;
```

How can I make sure that my CSS is in sync with development machine?

Comment: I have noticed that deleting running rm ./repo/public/assets/*css*
 and then running RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec "rake assets:precompile" fixes the problem, but is there way of doing it while performing git push?

Comment: If you are deploying by Capistrano, the task for precompiling assets comes by default in case you have uncommented `load 'deploy/assets'` in your `Capfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the Openshift deploy behavior through action hooks https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications